# Promise resolving to child stream stdout and rejecting child stream stderr

Tags: node.js, process, stream, promise, spawn

I'd like to build a promise that spawns a child process using `require('child_process').spawn`. The process streams its output to `stdout` and its errors to `stderr`.

I would like the promise to:

- `reject(child.stderr stream (or its data))` if `child.stderr` emits any data.
- `resolve(child.stdout stream)` only if no error is emitted.

I'm doing this because I want to chain the promise to:

- a `then` that processes the `child.stdout` stream (upload the stream to an S3 bucket).
- a `catch` that can process the child.stderr stream, allowing me to properly handle errors.

Is it feasible to combine promises and process streams like this ?
I was thinking of working around stderr but unsure about whats happening in between to stdout if a lot of data is coming into it and I don't process it fast enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it, the issue is that you don't know whether you ever got data on `stderr` until the entire process is done as it could put data there at any time.

So, you have to wait for the entire process to be done before calling `resolve()` or `reject()`. And, if you then want the entire data to be sent to either one of those, you'd have to buffer them. You could call `reject()` as soon as you got data on `stderr`, but you aren't guaranteed to have all the data yet because it's a stream.

So, if you don't want to buffer, you're better off just letting the caller see the streams directly.

If you are OK with buffering the data, you can buffer it yourself like this:

Based on the spawn example in the node.js doc, you could add promise support to it like this:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function runIt(cmd, args) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const ls = spawn(cmd, args);

        // Edit thomas.g: My child process generates binary data so I use buffers instead, see my comments inside the code 
        // Edit thomas.g: let stdoutData = new Buffer(0)
        let stdoutData = "";
        let stderrData= "";
        ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        // Edit thomas.g: stdoutData = Buffer.concat([stdoutData, chunk]);
            stdoutData += data;
        });

        ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            stderrData += data;
        });

        ls.on('close', (code) => {
            if (stderrData){
                reject(stderrData);
            } else {
                resolve(stdoutData);
            }
        });
        ls.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    }) 
}

//usage
runIt('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']).then(function(stdoutData) {
    // process stdout data here
}, function(err) {
    // process stdError data here or error object (if some other type of error)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's what I'm currently doing in fact. But I'd like to know if there is a way to reject(stderr) and resolve(stdout)

Comment: For instance I'd like to avoid having too much stuff inside stdoutData loaded in memory.

Comment: @thomas.g - As I see it, the issue is that you don't know whether you ever got data on stderr until the entire process is done as it could put data there at any time.  So, you have to wait for the entire process to be done before calling `resolve()` or `reject()`.  And, if you then want the entire data to be sent to either one of those, you'd have to buffer them.  You could call `reject()` as soon as you got data on stderr,, but you aren't guaranteed to have all the data yet because it's a stream.  If you don't want to buffer, you're better off just letting the caller see the streams directly.

Comment: @thomas.g - Adn seeing the streams directly is not really compatible with a one-time call to `resolve()` or `reject()` - e.g. not really compatible with promises here.

Comment: That's indeed my problem. I can't think of a good solution using promises and those two streams. So I'll have to keep buffering stdout and I'll have to stress test the API because I fear that such buffering might result to heavy memory pressure. Could you create an answer based on your comments so I can accept it ?

Comment: @thomas.g - I added my comment to the start of this answer.

Comment: I just had an idea in between that I want to test: I might be able to merge the two streams into one, re-emit the data that's coming from stdout and emit an error if anything comes from stderr. I'll give that a try !

Comment: It's definitely doable to implement the use case I was talking about (I just did it in fact), but in my case I'm not confident enough on the APIs that will consume the stream that results from the merge. @jfriend00's solution definitely leads to an easier to follow code which is fine by me as I'd have anyway to handle memory issues due to buffering.

Comment: Man you are a genius