# Why are these .then() occurring out of order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I've got a node application that `spawn`s a `child_process`. When the `child_process` is finished running, I'd like to resolve a promise. The following code works, but the `.then()` statements occur out of order:

```
const storage = require('./storage');
const logging = require('./logging');
const process = require('child_process').spawn;


function convertIncomingFile(pathToFile) {
  logging.info(`Converting ${pathToFile}`);
  const convert = process(`cat`, [pathToFile], {});

  return Promise.resolve(
    convert.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      logging.info(data.toString('utf8'));
    }),
    convert.stderr.on('data', (err) => {
      logging.error(err);
    }),
    convert.on('close', (code) => {
      logging.info(`Conversion finished with status code ${code}`);
    })
  );
}

module.exports = {
  convertFile: (filename) => {
    storage.downloadFile(filename).
      then((localFilename) => {
        logging.info(`File saved to: ${localFilename}`);
      }).
      then(() => convertIncomingFile(`./files/${filename}`)).
      then(() => {
        logging.info(`Coversion of ${filename} complete.`);
      }).
      catch((apiErr) => {
        logging.error(apiErr);
      });
  }
};
```

The output I get is:

```
info: File saved to: ./files/package.json
info: Converting ./files/package.json
info: Coversion of package.json complete.
info: {
 <file contents>
}

info: Conversion finished with status code 0
```

As you can see the `Conversion of package.json complete.` statement occurs before the file contents are logged and the conversion status code statement. Why is this the case and how do I get the 'Conversion complete' statement to come after the 'status code' statement?

Comment: I'm not sure what some of these are supposed to return, but I don't see any `return` statements that look like they'd be returning a promise...

Comment: Besides the `return Promise.resolve(...)`?

Comment: WTF? You're passing three arguments to `Promise.resolve` which only takes one, and nowhere are you awaiting the events. You need to properly promisify `spawn` with the `new Promise` constructor, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46289682/1048572) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35896832/1048572)

Comment: `convertIncomingFile` isn't called anywhere. Your `convertFile` is calling itself. This actually looks like an infinite loop. Also, it doesn't return anything, thus breaking the promise chain. Lastly, you could reduce this a bit by returning convertFile right after loggin.info(`File saved blah blah blah`) to reduce one of your `then`s

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It doesn't call itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.resolve` means return a solved value that you give it, it's not realy async as you expected. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise for more detailed info

```js
function convertIncomingFile(pathToFile) {
  logging.info(`Converting ${pathToFile}`);
  const convert = process(`cat`, [pathToFile], {});

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    convert.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        logging.info(data.toString('utf8'));
      }),
      convert.stderr.on('data', (err) => {
        logging.error(err);
        reject()
      }),
      convert.on('close', (code) => {
        logging.info(`Conversion finished with status code ${code}`);
        resolve()
      })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `convertFile` promise further to let next `then` know that it has to wait:

```
then(() => {
  return convertFile(`./files/${filename}`);
})
```

and shorter equivalent:

```
then(() => convertFile(`./files/${filename}`))
```

Comment: Hmm, that seems to give the same result. I've updated my code where `convertFile` is returned

Comment: I think you meant to change it to convertIncomingFile.

Comment: Right you are, fixed that.